# Import Excel file with subtitles and timestamps

Tags: video, subtitles

I typed up a transcript of a video, and inserted time stamps at the beginning of each change of speaker, using https://transcribe.wreally.com/.  Then I put everything into Excel.  I copied the timestamp column and pasted it into a new column to its right, but moving the whole thing up one row.  I figured that would make the segments abut perfectly.  I added an empty additional column where the program would expect to see where each segment ended (where the new one start.

Then I followed the instructions at https://video.stackexchange.com/a/14518/19609 and installed [Subtitle Edit](http://www.nikse.dk/SubtitleEdit).  I tried pasting the columns of data in, and I tried opening the tab-delimited file I had made.  It's giving me nonsense in the second column (which indicates the end timestamp).

What software and method can I use for getting my typed transcript into a properly formatted srt file, so I can publish it with Youtube?

Comment: Sometimes YouTube will generate subtitles for you. You might be doing work you don't have to do anyway.

Comment: Turns out my timestamps were all shifted.  When I corrected them things worked. "Subtitle Edit" (free, open source) was helpful and not as resource-hoggy as Aegisub -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle_Edit. // @DigiVisionMedia - as I was fiddling around, I experimented with the automatic captioning.  It worked on a short segment but not on the whole recording, which was quite long.  Also, since there were multiple speakers, less than optimal audio quality, and some overlapping voices, the automatically generated transcript was of limited usefulness.

Comment: Yes, that's been my experience too. I can't seem to find any logic behind YouTube's automatic caption decisions. It seems there's a sweet spot for length and content. It's not too useful to me either (my content is mostly one hour lectures) mostly because it's unpredictable.